# Accessing /me endpoint with azuread v2.0 and personal accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to have access to information in "/me" with Graph API for a personal account using Azure AD v2.0 but I receive the following error. It works with organizational accounts.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"Status\":500,\"Message\":\"All the offeractions povided in the property bag cannot be validated for the token.\\u000d\\u000a\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "39e23062-80ad-4872-86a7-39f5a5d928ce",
      "date": "2017-02-23T15:35:06"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the permission `User.ReadBasic.All`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope User.ReadBasic.All grant the permission to read the basic profile of all users in the organization on behalf of the signed-in user. This scope is t only supported for the Azure AD Account. If you just want to read the user’s profile for the Microsoft Account, you could use the scope User.Read . Code flow steps below is for your reference :

Get the authorization code :

```
Get : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&state=af0ifjsldkj&nonce=n-0S6_WzA2Mj
```

Then get the token :

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&state=af0ifjsldkj&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2F&client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client secret>
```